# no instance of overloaded function.... (messagebox::show)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Apparently, my argument doesn't match the argument list.

Here is the line:

```
MessageBox::Show("Credits:\n [bla bla bla]\n [bla bla bla]",
                 MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Asterisk);
```

Can anyone explain what's going on? Do I need individual strings for each expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no overload that takes a single string, message box button and message box icon. You need an extra `string` for the title:

```
MessageBox::Show("Credits:\n [bla bla bla]\n [bla bla bla]", "Title",
              MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Asterisk);
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y(v=vs.110).aspx)

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) has a complete list of the overloads that are available.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but looking back at my C# days I figured out that it only allows two strings, one of which is the title of the message box. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking up the [`MessageBox::Show` overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1), which you could have done similarly using VS's intellisense, I've learned that there's in fact no such overload. The closest you can get is [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y(v=vs.110).aspx), with which you need to specify both text and title:

```
MessageBox::Show(String^ text, String^ caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for available functions. I think you could use [this version of `Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/365dky5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

```
DialogResult Show(
    String^ text,
    String^ caption,
    MessageBoxButtons buttons,
    MessageBoxIcon icon
)
```

It takes two strings: The content and the title of the message.